# Nagios orphaned services warnings

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios

We have had Nagios running on one of our servers with out any problems for a while but lately certain old service warning have been reappearing and then disappearing on the service detail page.

From looking at the logs I found warning like the following.

> Warning: The check of service 'Tomcat'
>   on host 'virtual1' looks like it was
>   orphaned (results never came back). 
>   I'm scheduling an immediate check of
>   the service...

Has anyone ever came across this before or at least know a way to delete the old Orphaned Warnings.

The Nagios Version we are running is Version 3.0b7 so an update might be in order.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated my Nagios version and it seemed to fix the problem.

Handy [How2](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/upgrading.html) update for anyone wants to upgrade.

Comment: +1 for the self answer ;-)